# Need help to modify flood fill algorithm

Tags: python, recursion, flood-fill

I'm trying to modify the flood fill algorithm to return the final 2D matrix, where all color1 only is colored with color2. The flooding should start from x, y in the matrix.

Test case 1:

Before:

```
matrix = [[4, 3, 1, 2],
          [3, 1, 1, 2],
          [1, 2, 4, 5]]
```

After `matrix = fill(matrix, x = 0, y = 2, color1 = 1, color2 = 2)`

```
matrix = [[4, 3, 2, 2],
          [3, 2, 2, 2],
          [1, 2, 4, 5]]
```

Test case 2:

Before:

```
matrix = [[3, 2, 4],
          [5, 1, 4],
          [4, 3, 1]]
```

After `matrix = fill(matrix, x = 0, y = 0, color1 = 3, color2 = 1)`

```
matrix = [[1, 2, 4],
          [5, 1, 4],
          [4, 3, 1]]
```

Test case 3:

Before:

```
matrix = [[2, 1, 1],
          [2, 1, 2],
          [2, 2, 2]]
```

After `matrix = fill(matrix, x = 1, y = 2, color1 = 2, color2 = 1)`

```
matrix = [[1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1]]
```

This is very analogous to the Zombie infection problem I found at [Invent with Python Blog](http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2011/08/11/recursion-explained-with-the-flood-fill-algorithm-and-zombies-and-cats/)

Currently, I have the algorithm that only modifies a global matrix.

```
def fill(matrix, x, y, color1, color2):

    matWidth = len(matrix)
    matHeight = len(matrix[0])
    if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= matWidth or y >= matHeight:
        return  

    if matrix[x][y] == color2 or matrix[x][y] != color1:
        return
    if matrix[x][y] == color1:
        matrix[x][y] = color2

    fill(matrix, x - 1, y, color1, color2)
    fill(matrix, x + 1, y, color1, color2)
    fill(matrix, x, y - 1, color1, color2)
    fill(matrix, x, y + 1, color1, color2)
```

Is there a way to modify fill() in such a way that it takes in matrix as an argument and returns the final filled matrix?

Thanks a lot!

I'm very close to solving this. Here's my solution:

```
def fill(matrix, x, y, color1, color2):
    matWidth = len(matrix)
    matHeight = len(matrix[0])

    if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= matWidth or y >= matHeight:
        return matrix  

    if mat[x][y] != color1:
        return matrix

    else:
        matrix[x][y] = color2
    if x == 0:
        if y == 0:
            if matrix[x + 1][y] == color1 and color[x + 1][y] != color2:
                matrix = fill(matrix, x + 1, y, color1, color2)
            if matrix[x][y + 1] == color1 and matrix[x][y + 1] != color2:
                matrix = fill(matrix, x, y + 1, color1, color2)
        if y == matHeight - 1:
            if matrix[x][y - 1] == color1 and matrix[x][y - 1] != color2:
                matrix = fill(matrix, x, y - 1, color1, color2)
            if matrix[x + 1][y] == color1 and matrix[x + 1][y] != color2:
                matrix = fill(matrix, x + 1, y, color1, color2)
        else:
            if matrix[x][y - 1] == color1 and matrix[x][y - 1] != color2:
                matrix = fill(matrix, x, y - 1, color1, color2)
            if matrix[x][y + 1] == color1 and matrix[x][y + 1] != color2:
                matrix = fill(matrix, x, y + 1, color1, color2)
            if matrix[x + 1][y] == color1 and matrix[x + 1][y] != color2:
                matrix = fill(matrix, x + 1, y, color1, color2)
    if x == matWidth - 1:
        if y == 0:
            if matrix[x - 1][y] == color1 and matrix[x - 1][y] != color2:
                matrix = fill(matrix, x - 1, y, color1, color2)
            if matrix[x][y + 1] == color1 and matrix[x][y + 1] != color2:
                matrix = fill(matrix, x, y + 1, color1, color2)
        if y == matHeight - 1:
            if matrix[x][y - 1] == color1 and matrix[x][y - 1] != color2:
                matrix = fill(matrix, x, y - 1, color1, color2)
            if matrix[x - 1][y] == color1 and matrix[x - 1][y] != color2:
                matrix = fill(matrix, x - 1, y, color1, color2)
        else:
            if matrix[x][y - 1] == color1 and matrix[x][y - 1] != color2:
                matrix = fill(matrix, x, y - 1, color1, color2)
            if matrix[x][y + 1] == color1 and matrix[x][y + 1] != color2:
                matrix = fill(matrix, x, y + 1, color1, color2)
            if matrix[x - 1][y] == color1 and matrix[x - 1][y] != color2:
                matrix = fill(matrix, x - 1, y, color1, color2)

    if y > 0 and matrix[x][y-1] == color1 and matrix[x][y-1] != color2:
        matrix = fill(matrix, x, y-1, color1, color2)

    if y < matHeight and matrix[x][y+1] == color1 and matrix[x][y+1] != color2:
        matrix = fill(matrix, x, y-1, color1, color2)

    if x < matWidth and matrix[x+1][y] == color1 and matrix[x+1][y] != color2:
        matrix = fill(matrix, x+1, y, color1, color2)

    if x > 0 and matrix[x-1][y] == color1 and matrix[x-1][y] != color2:
        matrix = fill(matrix, x-1, y, color1, color2)

    return matrix
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You need a copy of the matrix, read https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: Why are you trying to do this recursively, it's extremely inefficient. Just use nested `for` loops to visit all the cell of the matrix and replace any that are color1 with color2. If the matrix is an argument to the function, it will change the values in it so there really no need to return it (but you could if you wished).

Comment: @martineau thanks for the response. I'll put in an edit. The problem states that the x, y are the starting position to flood. That way, we can't use nested loops. :/

Comment: @ishaan I read the docs, I dont think I understood how I can solve it with the deepcopy.

Comment: I don't get it. Why don't you just do `return matrix` at the end and at the other places where you return?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I tried. Wouldn't work. I tried returning the matrix unchanged from each return and at the color2 modification step returned the changed matrix.

However, it fails because when I am receiving the return as `matrix = fill(matrix, x (+/-1), y(+/-1), color1, color2)`, it may receive an unchanged matrix and return it from the depth 1 call, therefore not producing the required answer.

Comment: @user3566440 I have no idea what you're trying to say. But you're probably doing it wrong. Would help if you told us where it can be tested (I assume it's some coding practice website).

Comment: Or give us a sample input and show us how your solutions fail it.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Yes, I realized that I'm not being too coherent. Apologies. I'll add a test case as an edit.

Comment: @user3566440 Ok I just tried it and what I suggested works perfectly.

Comment: Great! Would you mind posting it as an answer? I tried what you said and maybe I missed something because I went into a stack overflow. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply return the matrix:

```
def fill(matrix, x, y, color1, color2):

    matWidth = len(matrix)
    matHeight = len(matrix[0])
    if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= matWidth or y >= matHeight:
        return matrix

    if matrix[x][y] == color2 or matrix[x][y] != color1:
        return matrix
    if matrix[x][y] == color1:
        matrix[x][y] = color2

    fill(matrix, x - 1, y, color1, color2)
    fill(matrix, x + 1, y, color1, color2)
    fill(matrix, x, y - 1, color1, color2)
    fill(matrix, x, y + 1, color1, color2)

    return matrix
```

Or if you don't like always returning it, use a wrapper to only return it once at the end:

```
def fill(matrix, x, y, color1, color2):
    def fill(matrix, x, y, color1, color2):

        matWidth = len(matrix)
        matHeight = len(matrix[0])
        if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= matWidth or y >= matHeight:
            return  

        if matrix[x][y] == color2 or matrix[x][y] != color1:
            return
        if matrix[x][y] == color1:
            matrix[x][y] = color2

        fill(matrix, x - 1, y, color1, color2)
        fill(matrix, x + 1, y, color1, color2)
        fill(matrix, x, y - 1, color1, color2)
        fill(matrix, x, y + 1, color1, color2)
    fill(matrix, x, y, color1, color2)
    return matrix
```

In that case you can also get rid of most parameters. Here's a version where I did that and also made the code a bit simpler:

```
def fill(matrix, x, y, color1, color2):
    def fill(x, y):
        if 0 <= x < matWidth and 0 <= y < matHeight and matrix[x][y] == color1:
            matrix[x][y] = color2
            fill(x - 1, y)
            fill(x + 1, y)
            fill(x, y - 1)
            fill(x, y + 1)
    matWidth = len(matrix)
    matHeight = len(matrix[0])
    fill(x, y)
    return matrix
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm. Wanted to upvote the answer, but I dont have enough reputation. :/

Comment: Modifying the matrix in-place *and* returning it is almost always a bad idea. You need to pick one or the other and be consistent. If you need to, make a copy: `matrix = matrix[:]`.

Comment: I did not know that a function could act as a wrapper. Awesome!

Comment: @MarkRansom *"You need to pick one or the other"* No I don't. I'd agree with "should", but not with "need".

Comment: @StefanPochmann it's a source of programming errors. I'll stick with my strong language, thanks.

Comment: @MarkRansom And I'll stick with the truth :-). I consider your `matrix = matrix[:]` to be **more** dangerous, btw, as that's only a shallow copy and thus rather pointless and misleading.

Comment: You're right, a shallow copy is insufficient in this case. My bad. I'll amend my recommendation to `matrix = copy.deepcopy(matrix)`.